# The fine line between duplicate and not

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've seen (and participated in) a few questions that got closed as duplicates, but I feel very strongly that even though they are related (and closely at that), the questions aren't *quite* duplicates. Here are a couple:

[Whats wrong with this simple 'double' calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707397/whats-wrong-with-this-simple-double-calculation)

[Can final static change when referring to method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278710/can-final-static-change-when-referring-to-method)

Both of these questions are marked as duplicates, but the original questions both sought a way to work around or fix the problem, while both of these questions seek a better understanding of what is going on. (The second one is a bit less clear in what it's asking, but I think that's a reasonable conclusion based on the accepted answer's content.) Put another way, the originals ask for a how, and these ask for a why. As such, I feel they are not duplicates since they are geared to elicit different kinds of answers. Is my view incorrect, or are there guidelines that would contradict my thinking? If I'm correct, how should I address the closure?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 - see section "2. You discover that duplicate only looks similar..."

Comment: @gnat Thanks. My searching didn't turn that up, but I don't think I searched MSE explicitly. (I probably should've with the split going on and all.) Also, that's a great answer. So if I'm not the asker, but instead someone trying to answer, it sounds like my best option is to encourage the asker to clarify the question to make the difference clear.

Comment: Here's an excellent example of the "fine line" (here, not duplicate, but the voters selected other reasons)  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23827935/294884  Note my comments with popeye.

Comment: From my point of view the are NOT duplicated question, there are duplicated ANSWERS to a same matter that arrive at different minds in different times. But of course, thinking like this required to much change in our minds and in the stackoverflow-system, so.. for me duplicating question is JUST the BEST that can happen. Image a class room, what happen to a teacher if he has to answer different question all the times? How he could archive the expertise in teaching? I do believe that POST duplicated MUST not be closed. It SHOULD be grouped. Thanks and god speed!

Comment: @Victor: That's what our duplicate closure does: it groups the questions.